# 'Const' Is not defined. (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, distube

I'm making a music bot, and I wanted to add an Embed when it returns a message, and I get an error saying const is not defined.

Here's my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client({
    partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION']

});
const config = require('./settings.json');
const { loadCommands } = require('./utils/loadCommands');
const DisTube = require('distube');


bot.distube = new DisTube(bot, { searchSongs: false, emitNewSongOnly: true });
bot.distube
    .on("playSong", (message, queue, song) => message.channel.send(
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()   
        .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Playing Now:')
    .setDescription('`${song.name}`')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Requested by: ${song.user}');        


    .on("addSong", (message, queue, song) => message.channel.send(
        .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Added to Queue:')
    .setDescription('\`${song.name}\`')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('${song.formattedDuration} - Requested by ${song.user}');         

require('./utils/loadEvents')(bot);

bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
bot.aliases = new Discord.Collection();

loadCommands(bot);

bot.login(config.token);
```

And then after I run it, I get this error:

```
const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
←[90m    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:16)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1072:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)←[39m
```

Comment: `message.channel.send(   const exampleEmbed = new D ...`

Comment: You can't initialize a variable inside a function parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used discord js, but from a quick look at the docs i guess you should do something like first declare your variable and then send it

```
bot.distube
    .on("playSong", (message, queue, song) => {
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
           .setColor('#0099ff')
         .setTitle('Playing Now:')
         .setDescription('`${song.name}`')
         .setTimestamp()
         .setFooter(`Requested by: ${song.user}`);  

     message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
}
```

There are 2 more problems.

1. Careful that `.setFooter('Requested by: ${song.user}')` template string should be with back ticks ' ` ' . see below

```
.setFooter(`Requested by: ${song.user}`)
```

2. your event listeners ( playSong and addSong ) and your `send` method seem like they are not ' closed ' with closing `)`

Read more here -> [embed discord](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-richembedmessageembed-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like channel.send() takes a string or embed as a parameter.  You should define the message in the outer lambda before sending:

```
// abbreviated code to relevant snippet
bot.distube = new DisTube(bot, { searchSongs: false, emitNewSongOnly: true });
bot.distube
   .on("playSong", (message, queue, song) => {
       const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
           ...
       message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
   });
```